# Where are the unmarked maps for Scales of War?

Tags: dnd-4e, published-adventures, content-identification, maps

I'm a DM about to start a campaign of Scales of War with my group. I have all of the stuff ready, except for the maps. I purchased a DDI Subscription through Digital River, but when I downloaded the maps from the Map Gallery of DDI, the files contained the DM's marked maps. I had heard there were unmarked versions, but the "No Tags" folder is empty. I would much prefer an unmarked version of the maps to use with my group. Does anyone know something I'm missing or will need to do?

I have also read more recently that only some issues of the Dungeon have no DM markings in the map documents, so I think this is maybe a solved issue. If anyone has any other information, please let me know.